# Eevee thin glass surface

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, glass

I am experimenting a bit with Eevee to get used to it but I can't render correctly objects with a thin glass surface (a sphere with solidify modifier for instance). Instead Eevee renders an object filled with glass (a ball with the same example). And it is the same with non closed surfaces.

Is there any way to make Eevee interpret it as a hollow object instead of a plain one ?

Here is a [scene](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SfPEIrP8OX1jqXqKmK7iR7NFla_9nK6L) rendered both with Cycles (which renders it correctly) and Eevee to illustrate :

[image: Suzanne's spacecraft in Cycles]

[image: Suzanne's spacecraft in Cycles]

[image: Suzanne's spacecraft in Eevee]

[image: Suzanne's spacecraft in Eevee]

Thanks for you answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your material a small refraction depth.

[image: evee material settings]

From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#screen-space-refraction)

> If Refraction Depth is not 0.0, all refraction BSDFs in the shader will act as if the object is a thin slab of the refraction material having this thickness. This will model a second refraction event that will double the absorption color and start the refraction ray after this second event.
>
> This option greatly increases the quality of thin glass objects.