# Invisible material node tree?

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass, shader-nodes

**so im making a fluid simulation where you see through an aquarium and i want to know how to make something like glass material, it has to be eevee engine though.**

> "my pc is potato pc lol" me, 2022 march 31rst 18:15

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150418/eevee-thin-glass-surface - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216244/110840